# JPA Hibernate and AuditJoinTable

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, audit

I'm stuck with creating audit tables. I have two collections one-to-many relationships. Once is inverse, other one is not. The auditjointable annotation works for non-inversed releation but not for the inversed one.

My code

```
@Entity
@Audited
@AuditTable(value = "DDD")
public class Department {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Audited
    private int id;
    private int age;

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(targetEntity = Professor.class,cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "dept_id")
    @AuditJoinTable(name = "abc")
    private java.util.Collection<Professor> employees;

    @OneToMany(targetEntity = Address.class, mappedBy = "department")<==inverse relation
    @AuditJoinTable(name = "def")
//I tried commenting this out and let the inverse side AuditJoinTable annotation, no luck 
    private java.util.Collection<Address> addresses;
//Getters and setters remove to reduce clutter
}
```

Address

```
    @Entity
    @Audited
    public class Address {
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        private int id;
        @Column
        private String name;

        @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
        @AuditJoinTable(name = "def")
        private Department department;
```

Professor

```
@Entity
@Audited
public class Professor {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
    @Column
    private String name;
    private long salary;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "dept_id")
    private Department department;

}
```

When I create the scema using hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto "def" autdit table is not generated. However "abc" audit jointable is generated and when the employees collection is updated the audit entries are logged.

I'm using
 hibernate/hibernate-envers - 3.6.9.Final
 JPA 1.0

Any pointers appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok after lot of digging still didn't find a way to get it working. However, the audit table for the Address entity will have a column to track the foreign key for Department. I enabled the

`"hibernate.ejb.event.post-update"`

Then any removal, updates for the collection will be tracked and the Address audit table will be updated.